# Web API Help is not generated as expected

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
[RoutePrefix("Office")]
public class OfficeController : ApiController
{

        [Route("~/Admin/{adid}")]
        public string GetAdminById(int adid) 
        {
            return string.Format("Enter value is {0}", adid);
        }
        [Route("~/User/{uid}")]
        public string GetUserByName(int uid)
        {
            return string.Format("Enter value is {0}", uid);
        }
    }
```

but help is generated below

```
GET api/Office?adminid={adid}
GET api/Office?userid={uid}
```

but I am excepting

```
GET Office/Admin/adid   
GET Office/User/uid
```

For this I added **one more** route, for admin at `webapi.config`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "OfficeadminApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Admin/{adid}",
           defaults: new { **adid** = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

then **2 signatures** are generated by web api help are

```
GET api/Office?adid={adid}
GET api/Office/Admin/{adid}  // I expected is generated but
```

what is the use of Attribute routing, if added no'f Routes at webapi.config?

as per Attribute routing it should generates, routes specified at attribute level.

Please clarify on this any one please ?